# UITableView don't seem to link to my assets.sxassets folder for images?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimage

I'm currently trying to get a `UITableView` working but I'm having issues trying to get the image to pop up in the code I'm writing, I've looked online and it always just seems to pop up! just incase this matters, this is view controller called TableViewController and it IS linked to the Storyboard ViewController... this is the code I'm having issues with here:

```
import UIKit
```

`struct CellData {
    let image : UIImage?
    let message : String?
}`

`class TableViewController: UITableViewController {`

`var data = [CellData]()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    data = [CellData.init(image: continue, message: "Hello")]
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}
```

`}`

Where I say `data = [CellData.init(image: continue, message: "Hello")]` **Image: continue** doesn't seem to know anything about the image called continue and I know its ok because I've already used it on my initial view controller...
im not sure if this matters too, but why would it have a **?** and what does the letters mean?

I'm not sure if this matters too, but why would it have a **?**

[image: screenshot]]

Comment: These letters indicate git status on those files. A = Added, M = Modified, ? = not added to git/source control. **continue** is a keyword in Swift (used in for loops.. break, continue etc). so you should try to avoid using reserved words. try cleaning your project. what code do you have in cellForRowAt? you need to return a cell with your data/image in it for it to display

Answer (score 1):

Try this, make sure you have image in assets with name of continue

```
let img = UIImage(named: "continue")
data = [CellData.init(image: img, message: "Hello")]
```

And its an **source control status A = Added, M = Modified. ? = not in source control**

Comment: Ok so that seemed to clear the error as id expect but ill have to get back to you with weather it worked yet once im done! thanks heaps

Comment: now that i look further into it, it seem like the view controller(s) just cant see the assets folder at all...

Comment: in all the swift toutorial ive watched, just typing the code in, works, i seem to always get "Use of unresolved identifier 'img1'" etc... any insight?

Comment: It means you are declared variable but not utilized it anywhere

Comment: But this isn’t a variable? This SHOULD be assigning image: to the image in my assets... and it IS available in there, it just doesn’t seem to be able to access it?

Comment: can you pls edit your question with updated code and add screenshot of your asset